# Polymer 1.0 dom-repeat with filter: action on visible items?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a dom-repeat with a dynamic filter depending on a paper-input value.

I need to apply an action to only the visible items, in other words only to those items passing the filter function (returning true)

Within that action function, how can I know which item is visible and which is not?

p.s. Looping the items array won't tell anything because the filter doesn't alter the items array. I am guessing there might be a way of looping the associated dom checking for some property or class, or otherwise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume one of the dom apis should work for you. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api. You can try one each one o

Comment: thanks @Srik that should work, or at least it looks like it's there, but no idea how to navigate it, so far

Comment: thanks again @Srik, I got it working, kind of rough yet. It feels like hacking though.